# Modal Window not Closing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom-events

I have created  a modal using HTML, CSS and JavaScript wherein I can open 2 modal windows together, 
and I can close them one-by-one ( i.e. closing the second one keeps the first window still active just like I want).

It's working all good no issues till here.

I am first attaching these working codes so that you can later compare it with bugged JavaScript code:

```
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].style.display = "none";
          open_modals.pop();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].style.display = "none";
          open_modals.pop();

        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <h2 class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">Enable Second Modal Window by tapping on this text</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
        <p>Modal Header 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        <h2 class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">You have opened modal window no.2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0.1875em;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625em solid #888;
  width: 97%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375em 1.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25em;
  top: -0.25em;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125em 1em;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.50vw;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**Now the real issue why I have posted this**
I wanted to add bottom sliding Animation while modal window closes, so I defined the Animation in CSS and added the same in JavaScript through `setTimeout` function.

Now here I was successful in adding the Animation but I messed something up.

If you open both the modal windows (first open 1 window, then through the text in the body of that window, you can open the second one) and try to close them `one-by-one`.

Only the second window will get closed, the first window doesn't get closed at all
(If you simply open the first window and try it close it, it does so pretty well. The issue only happens with first window's closure Activity when both windows are opened).

Now I am attaching the JavaScript codes where I added `setTimeout` and messed something which is causing the above-mentioned issue:

```
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");

          setTimeout(function(){
            for (var index in modals) {
            modals[index].classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            modal.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            }
          },400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");

          setTimeout(function(){
            for (var index in modals) {
            modals[index].classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            modal.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();
            }
          },400);

        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Can someone please adjust the JavaScript code in such a way that it fixes the above-mentioned issue while having my `setTimeout` animations too?
**(You may compare the original working JavaScript without setTimeout-animations at the top with the below-bugged JavaScript code to do this easily )**.

**Update: Console gives the following error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

with the bugged JavaScript code mentioned at the bottom

If someone wants to see the bugged code in action here you go - https://jsbin.com/cisanigihu/1/edit?output

Comment: Do u want to close the modal box one-by-one? using his close icon?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 yes i intent to close them one-by-one through the close icon and through Clicking outside of window

Comment: Using close icon its working fine in one-by-one.. Now outside window not working.. Is this ur pbm?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 close icon and outside window both are not working if you try the modified/bugged JavaScript code given at bottom. ( The one given at top is perfect code no issues. I messed it up in process of adding animation through settimeout )

Comment: Is there any errorshowing in console?

Comment: I think it would be best to post your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Dumisani yep i updated post with jsbin link.  And also updated with the console error.   Hope it helps the users in fixing my JavaScript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you `pop` all open modals in the `setTimeout`, you should `pop` just latest modal. I fixed your code in the below snippet:

```js
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

    // All page modals
    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
            modal.style.display = "block";
            open_modals.push(modal.id);
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].onclick = function() {
            for (var index in modals) {
                if (modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
                  var modal = modals[index];
                    modal.classList.add("modal-content-active");

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        modal.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                        open_modals.pop();
                    }, 400);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
            for (var index in modals) {
                if (modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
                    var modal = modals[index];
                    modal.classList.add("modal-content-active");

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        modal.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                        open_modals.pop();
                    }, 400);

                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0.1875em;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625em solid #888;
  width: 97%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375em 1.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25em;
  top: -0.25em;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125em 1em;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.50vw;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">
            <p>Modal Header</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
            <h2 class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">Enable Second Modal Window by tapping on this text</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <div class="headertext">
            <p>Modal Header 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
        <div class="bodytext">
            <h2 class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">You have opened modal window no.2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: On an other note , a friend of mine fixed it too.  But his codes are little different - https://del.dog/xebibotisu.json.  Can you please suggest which approach will be better